# Showing irreducibility is invariant under conjugation in quadratic integers

Tags: number-theory, extension-field, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

I found the following statement in a paper I'm reading on (the integers in) a quadratic field:

**If** $\alpha =a+b\sqrt{D}$ **is an irreducible element of** $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$, **then so is** $\bar{\alpha}=a-b\sqrt{D}$

I'm having quite a bit of trouble showing that this is true (and the paper doesn't specify whether it is only true when $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ is a UFD or not), but here is my attempt for the case when $D<-1$:

Suppose for a contradiction that $\alpha =a+b\sqrt{D}$ irreducible, but that $ \bar{\alpha} =a-b\sqrt{D}$ is not. Consider: 
$$ a^2-Db^2=(a+b\sqrt{D})(a-b\sqrt{D})$$
Since $a-b\sqrt{D}$ isn't irreducible, it has an irreducible factor $x+y\sqrt{D}$ ([$\ast$] for which we assume that both $x\neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$. This implies that $\gcd_{\mathbb{Z}}(x,y)=1$ when $D<-1$), so $\alpha=(x+y\sqrt{D})\beta$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ and thus: 
$$ a^2-Db^2=(a+b\sqrt{D})(x+y\sqrt{D})\beta$$
Dividing this equation throughout by $x+y\sqrt{D}$, we get 
$$\frac{x(a^2-Db^2)}{x^2-Dy^2}-\frac{y(a^2-Db^2)}{x^2-Dy^2}\sqrt{D}=(a+b\sqrt{D})\beta$$
Now, since the right hand side clearly is an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$, the left hand side must also be. Therefore $(x^2-Dy^2) \;|\; x(a^2-Db^2)$ and $(x^2-Dy^2) \;|\; y(a^2-Db^2)$, but since $(x,y)=1$ by the remark $[\ast]$ it forces that $(x^2-Dy^2)\; |\;(a^2-Db^2)$.

The point is that $x-y\sqrt{D}$ is a factor of $a^2-Db^2$, but since $a+b\sqrt{D}$ and $x+y\sqrt{D}$ are assumed to be irreducible, we must have $x-y\sqrt{D}\; | \; \beta$. Therefore: 
$$a^2-Db^2=(a+b\sqrt{D})(x+y\sqrt{D})(x-y\sqrt{D})\gamma$$
Where the two first factors are irreducible.

I don't know how to finish the 'proof' attempt, or if it even can be turned into a proof. Surely, we have started some sort of process of factorization that cannot go on indefinately if $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ is a UFD (since $a^2-Db^2$ has finite norm). So: Does anyone know how to prove the statement and/ or its range of validety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. The right tool is the following theorem:

**Thm.** Let $f:A\to B$ be a ring isomorphism. Then $\pi\in A$ is irreducible if and only if $f(\pi)$ is irreducible.

**Proof.** Clearly, it is enough to prove that if $\pi$ is irreducible , then $f(\pi)$ is irreducible (for the reverse implication replace $f$ by $f^{-1}$).

Since $f$ is an isomorphism, since $\pi$ is nonzero and non invertible (zero is maaped on to zero, and units are mapped onto units), so is $f(\pi)$.

Let $b,b'\in B$ such that $f(\pi)= bb'$. Since $f$ is surjective, we may write $b=f(a),b'=f(a')$ for some $a,a'\in A$.

Then $f(\pi)=f(a)f(a')=f(aa')$, so $\pi=aa'$, by injectivity of $f$. By assumption on $\pi$, $a$ or $a'$ is invertible, say $a$. But then $b=f(a)$ is invertible.

Consequently, $f(\pi)$ is irreducible.

Now apply this to your ring, where $f$ is conjugation. Of course, if you don't like this amount of generality, you can apply the same reasoning to your specific case.

Comment: No, the level of generality is no problem :) Thanks!